# Spring Boot Exclude Tomcat Dependency

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, jhipster

In the default [JHipster](http://jhipster.github.io) configuration the `spring-boot-starter-web` has the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` excluded from its dependencies.  Reasons for excluding the tomcat dependency can include:

- Deploying war into separate standalone web application server
- Swapping the Tomcat dependency for another web server such as Jetty

(Excerpt from [pom.xml](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/_pom.xml#L494))

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Additionally 2 profiles are provided for running the application in `dev` or `prod` environments.  This is where my confusion starts...

In each profile, an additional dependency is declared:

```
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        ...
    </profile>
```

**Is there a reason why the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency needs to be excluded in the list of standard dependencies and then included in the profiles?**

**Wouldn't it be better to remove the exclusion from the dependencies and have:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Why don't you try? and if it works open an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact legacy code: we used to have a "fast" profile where we would use Undertow instead of Tomcat, and that's why the Tomcat dependency was removed by default.
We've been keeping this because we'd like to migrate to Undertow again, but last time we tried we had [another issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2948)... So maybe we should remove this.